# Combining Includes with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I generally use a generic repository to boilerplate my EF queries so I have to write limited code and also use caching. The source code for the repository can be found [here](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/EFBootstrap).

The backbone query within the code is this one below. `FromCache<T>()` is an `IEnumerable<T>` extension method that utilizes the `HttpContext.Cache` to store the query using a stringified representation of the lambda expression as a key.

```cs
    public IQueryable<T> Any<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null)
    where T : class, new()
    {
        // Check for a filtering expression and pull all if not.
        if (expression == null)
        {
            return this.context.Set<T>()
                       .AsNoTracking()
                       .FromCache<T>(null)
                       .AsQueryable();
        }

        return this.context.Set<T>()
                           .AsNoTracking<T>()
                           .Where<T>(expression)
                           .FromCache<T>(expression)
                           .AsQueryable<T>();
    }
```

Whilst this all works it is subject to the N+1 problem for related tables since If I were to write a query like so:

```cs
var posts = this.ReadOnlySession.Any<Post>(p => p.IsDeleted == false)
                                .Include(p => p.Author);
```

The `Include()` will have no effect on my query since it has already been run in order to be cached.

Now I know that I can force Entity Framework to use eager loading within my model by removing the virtual prefix on my navigation properties but that to me feels like the wrong place to do it as you cannot predict the types of queries you will be making. To me it feels like something I would be doing in a controller class. What I am wondering is whether I can pass a list of includes into my `Any<T>()` method that I could then iterate though when I make the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ofDid you mean something like...

```
IQueryable<T> AnyWithInclude<T,I>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate,
                                  Expression<Func<T,I>> includeInfo) 
{ 
  return  DbSet<T>.where(predicate).include(includeInfo);
}
```

the call

```
Context.YourDbSetReference.AnyWithInclude(t => t.Id==someId, i => i.someNavProp);
```

In response to extra question on as collection.

I realised late, there was an overload on Property. You can just pass a string

This might work but call is not easy. Well I find it hard.

```
   IQueryable<T> GetListWithInclude<I>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
                                        params Expression<Func<T, I>>[] IncludeCollection);
```

so i tried

```
 public virtual IQueryable<T> GetListWithInclude(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, 
                                                 List<string> includeCollection)
    { var result = EntityDbSet.Where(predicate);
        foreach (var incl in includeCollection)
        {
            result = result.Include(incl);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and called with

```
 var ic = new List<string>();
 ic.Add("Membership");
 var res =  context.DbSte<T>.GetListWithInclude( t=>t.UserName =="fred", ic);
```

worked as before.

Comment: btw i use something similar for projections ;-)

Comment: Could you possible expand your answer to more closely match the method I am currently using? I'm getting lost somewhat translating. Also would it be possible to pass a collection of includes as an argument?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I always forget about the `params` keyword for some reason. I'm thinking something like this might do it. It compiles though I check it properly just now. 

`IQueryable<T> AnyWithInclude<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null, params Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>[] includes) where T : class, new()`

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of clarity I'm adding the solution I came up with based upon @soadyp's answer.

```
public IQueryable<T> Any<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null, 
                         params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeCollection)
    where T : class, new()
{
    IQueryable<T> query = this.context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().AsQueryable<T>();

    if (includeCollection.Any())
    {
        query = includeCollection.Aggregate(query, 
                    (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    }

    // Check for a filtering expression and pull all if not.
    if (expression != null)
    {
        query = query.Where<T>(expression);
    }

    return query.FromCache<T>(expression, includeCollection)
                .AsQueryable<T>();
}
```

Usage:

```
// The second, third, fourth etc parameters are the strongly typed includes.
var posts = this.ReadOnlySession.Any<Post>(p => p.IsDeleted == false,
                                           p => p.Author);
```